# Generalising compile* task in Gradle

Tags: gradle

How do I generalise``compile` task in a multi-language project?

E.g. I can to generalise this to run on all `compile*` tasks for each language used.

```
compileJava {
    ajc {
        enabled = true 
        classpath = configurations.aspectj 
        options {
            aspectpath = configurations.aspect 
            compilerArgs = [] 
        }
    }
}
compileTestJava {
    ajc {
        enabled = true 
        classpath = configurations.aspectj 
        options {
            aspectpath = configurations.testAspect 
            compilerArgs = [] 
        }
    }
}
```

Source: [FreeFair Gradle Plugin Collection](https://docs.freefair.io/gradle-plugins/5.2.x/reference/#_io_freefair_aspectj_base)

How can the above be modified so that it can run with any `compile*` task, e.g. `compileGroovy`, `compileKotlin`, `compileScala` etc. in a multi-language project?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `matching(...)` of the [`TaskContainer`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html) that is available via `tasks` in your `build.gradle`:

```
tasks.matching { task -> task.name.startsWith('compile') }.all {
    ajc {
        enabled = true 
        classpath = configurations.aspectj 
        options {
            aspectpath = configurations.testAspect 
            compilerArgs = [] 
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that this solution will only work if all tasks that start with `'compile'` actually have an extension `ajc`. It also only works because of Groovy, as whether `afc` is available or not will be evaluated dynamically. This won't work in a Kotlin build script.